# Cloud Function with Cloud Function Invoker rights gets 403 status

Tags: google-cloud-functions, http-status-code-403, google-iam

I have two Cloud Functions: a frontend and an API. I have added a `frontend` service account to the frontend Cloud Function that has `Cloud Function Invoker` rights:

[image]

I have also explicitly added this service account as a permission to the API Cloud Function, yet I am still getting `403 Not Authorized` statuses.

[image]

```
 const categories = await this.$axios.$get("/api/v1/categories/", {
    params: { hasParent: 0 },
  });
```

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you call the API from the frontend?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere added the call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add the authorization header to make it work! It's not out of the box!

But, the cloud functions doc is bad to explain that. Use the [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service) documentation instead (the 2 services use the same underlying infrastructure and the principle are the same, the doc is simply easier to use on Cloud Run!!)

Comment: So if i understand correctly, BEFORE doing any calls from my frontend to my API I need to get the auth token from GCP?

Comment: Yes. And add it as header of your request. If your frontend run on Cloud Functions, it's not so difficult (share your code if you are still stuck to get the TokenID from the metadata server)